# popToRootViewControllerAnimated: always returns null

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm popping all of my `UIViewController` when I go to the first tab of my `UITabBar`.  The documentation for `UINavigationController`'s `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` is:

```
- (NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *> *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

> Return Value: An array of view controllers representing the items that were popped from the stack.

But I always get a null return value (even if I'm certain there were VCs to pop).  I should at least get an empty array, but I'm getting null.

Documentation or operator error?

I'm interesting in knowing from someone who is using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` what they get for a return value (even if unused).

Comment: Are you sure you’re popping a navigationController?

Comment: @Brandon.  The receiver is a Nav controller, for sure.  And there are VCs on the stack because they are popped.  So, the method is working.  But, I want to check the return array, but it's null.

Comment: @Rajesh, I'm not using a storyboard.  It's all code.  Anyway, it doesn't matter.  Why no return value?

Comment: I get an array of viewcontrolles when `popToRootViewController` is called. Try `print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)` before calling `popToRootViewController`

Comment: @Rajesh, the array of viewControllers before the pop is what I expect.  Most are just one VC for each tab, but one might have a VC that's been pushed (that's what I want to pop).  It pops, as expected.